# How to put out a complete string with {} in tcl

Tags: string, tcl

I have a line with special characters, I would like to do puts and newline everything in 1 LINE CODE.
How do I do that without having to care about special characters or split them into multiple puts line?

Example:

```
puts $infile {I_want_$_"put_exactly_this_out$"_to_$infile\nI_also$#_"\n}
```

Here is what the output file should look like:

```
I want to eat_1_2_$

"I want to sleep"

I go to school\
```

All of the above, I would like to do a puts in 1 LINE. So in the script, I try to do the following, but doesnt seem to work.

```
puts $outfile1 "I want to eat_1_2_$\n"I want to sleep"\nI go to school\"

puts $outfile1 {I want to eat_1_2_$\n"I want to sleep"\nI go to school\}
```

Comment: What do you want the printed string to look like?

Comment: _In extremis,_ you can always put everything in double quotes and put a backslash in front of all the Tcl metacharacters that you want to go out as-is.

Comment: I just want to save time and just do a 1 LINE PUTS

Answer (score 1):

The quotes you want to output need to be escaped:
Since you have characters you want interpreted (\n), using double quotes
is easier in this case.

```
puts stdout "I want to eat_1_2_\$\n\"I want to sleep\"\nI go to school\\"
```

When you have complicated strings that mix special characters and escaped sequences and variables, it is generally easier to simply build them up piece by piece.

```
set x {I want to eat_1_2_$}
append x \n
append x {"I want to sleep"}
append x \n
append x {I go to school\\}
puts stdout $x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
puts $out [string cat {I want to eat_1_2_$} \n {"I want to sleep"} \n {I go to school} \\]
```

or

```
puts $out [join {{I want to eat_1_2_$} {"I want to sleep"} "I go to school\\"} \n]
```